# Scale invariant measures must have power law densities

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory

If $\mu$ is a scale-invariant measure(say on $\mathbb{R}^{+}$), i.e. for any set $A$, $\mu\left(\frac{A}{c}\right)=g\left(c\right)\mu\left(A\right)$ where $c>0$,  then is it necessary that $g$ must be of the form $g\left(c\right)=c^{\alpha}$ and $\mu=x^{-1-\alpha}dx$ for some $\alpha$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to first show that $\mu(c^{-n} A) = g(c)^n \mu(A)$ by repeatedly applying the rule.  Then show $\mu(c^{-n/m} A) = g(c)^{n/m} \mu(A)$ for any non-zero integers $m$ and $n$.  Then show that $c \mapsto \mu(c^{-1} A)$ is a continuous function of $c$ (left or right continuous will be enough, and one of these can be obtained by the monotone convergence theorem).

So now you will have $\mu(c^{-\beta} A) = g(c)^\beta \mu(A)$.  Pick $c$ anything not equal to $1$ (but $c = e$ will make the argument easy), and you conclude that $\mu(A/x) = x^\alpha$ with $\alpha = \ln(g(c))/\ln(c)$.

To get the last part, consider $A = (0,1]$ and take differences to get a formula for $\mu((x,y])$  Any Borel measure on $\mathbb R_+$ is uniquely determined by its values on intervals.  But the formula is only correct up to an arbitrary constant multiple.

Comment: Thanks! Would you mind elaborating why showing the last bit will yield the conclusion?

Comment: @KartMan How about the edit I just made?